# How to declare the entity &nbsp; in XmlReader for Metro Style apps?

Tags: html, xml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, xmlreader

I am trying to parse through html and xhtml files using the XmlReader from the System.Xml namespace in Metro Style apps. I understand that this method may not be ideal because html documents may not necessarily be formatted in accordance with xml standards, but after extensive research, I have not been able to find a better way to parse these files (if I have overlooked something please let me know!).

My app keeps crashing whenever I try to read a file that contains "&nbsp", which is obviously due to the fact that the entity is an html one that does not exist in xml. I have read several other questions and posts about how to resolve this issue so that an XmlReader can work around this problem, but none of them work in my situation. I was wondering if there was a way to add a setting to my XmlReader that would enable it to interpret "&nbsp" as "&#160".

THESE ARE POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS THAT HAVE NOT/WOULD NOT WORK FOR ME:

- I cannot manually change the "&nbsp" to "&#160" in the html files because my app parses several html files from different sources, preventing me from manually editing an individual file.
- All files I have tried to parse with the following header:
  "!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">"

crash when the reader reaches that line (for some strange reason). The only way I could get past that line was to turn DtdProcessing to Ignore, which would ignore this line. If the Dtd had declared the entity &nbsp, then I effectively undo that.

OTHER INFO:
When I say that the app crashes, no exception is thrown by the debugger, but the app closes, and I get sent to this code

```
    #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
```

in a file called App.g.i.cs

Also, I am using Visual Studio 2012 for Win8 Metro Style.

Comment: Replacing "&nbsp" with "&#160" worked for me, so thanks for that hint.